# Magento Programaticallly add product, Image is not selected as small-image

Tags: php, magento

I'm trying to add a product programmatically in magento. Everything works file except images.

The images are uploaded and showing up on product page. however, it doesn't set as small-image or thumbnail.

At admin back-end side, it looks like this,
[image]

I use following code ,

```
$fullpath = 'upload/one.jpg';
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($fullpath, 'image', false);
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($fullpath, 'small_image', false);
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($fullpath, 'thumbnail', false);
```

I tried below code also with no luck,

```
$product->addImageToMediaGallery($fullpath, array('image', 'thumbnail', 'small_image'), false, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding

```
$product->setImage($fullpath);
$product->setImage($fullpath);
$product->setThumbnail($fullpath);
$product->save();
```

I didn't test it but took the idea from here: http://webkul.com/blog/magento-set-product-default-image-product-images/

Comment: Still Not working..  No any error but image is shown like this, http://s14.postimg.org/fcm5zql1d/prblm.jpg, http://s15.postimg.org/7m8l300h7/prblm2.jpg

Comment: can you provide some more code, especially lines before and after your already provided code? (how is the object in $product created?) Then I would try it by myself in a test installation and tell you if I could manage. Oh and try to clear cashes and reindex, maybe that could lead to problems too?